# Informing SP about session invalidated in IDP

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I was trying to use SAML through SSO,my question is when a session becomes invalid in IDP, how does IDP notifies this to SP, if I have multiple copy of SP sitting in geographically distributed region sitting behind a load balancer,how the message reaches a particular SP as the DNS name for all will be same.

Comment: you'll probably have to setup loadbalancer to distribute that type of call between all nodes

Comment: This is not possible with SAML because the spec doesn't say anything about session management. That's not its purpose. So, every suggestion you get will be bespoke or implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on specific IdP implementation. Some IdPs are using back channel. Sending SOAP message to inform all SP's that are in partner trust. OpenAM per instance is using this mechanism. Performing SLO request to all SP's.